# Using TextBox in PlayN without popup?

Tags: java, textbox, popup, field, playn

Is there any way to use textboxes (or Fields) in a PlayN application with TriplePlay, which captures input from the keyboard, without displaying a popup, just like a Swing application? This is meant for desktop, the Popup function may be used for Android.

Do I need to create my own textbox from scratch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there's still the old code but it was buggy, there are new attempts like Native*TextField, but it's not ready yet